# AngularJS: use filter to split array into arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, function, filter

There is an array of objects that I would like to split into several arrays.
These strings work perfect in AngularJS and split the whole array `arr` into four arrays the way I want:

```
    var arr0 = $filter('filter')(arr, { filterVal: 0 }, true);
    var arr1 = $filter('filter')(arr, { filterVal: 10 }, true);
    var arr2 = $filter('filter')(arr, { filterVal: 50 }, true);
    var arr3 = $filter('filter')(arr, { filterVal: 60 }, true);
```

Actually, the four arrays above total are the original array (because `filterVal` in each item is always equal to `0, 10, 50 or 60`).

So, the question is how to make the code above shorter? So, I need to split `arr` into new_arr in one line so that

```
new_arr[0] is equal to arr0,
new_arr[1] is equal to arr1,
new_arr[2] is equal to arr2,
new_arr[3] is equal to arr3.
```

**With another words,** I would like to use one string of code (if possible) instead of four strings. Is it possible with AngularJS?

This way I would make it more dynamic (not stick to four).

Thank you.

**Just added:**
As example,

```
    arr = [
        {"code":"kfk", "flag":"dfmk", "filterVal": 0},
        {"code":"asg", "flag":"sdg3", "filterVal": 50},
        {"code":"asdf", "flag":"34t", "filterVal": 10},
        {"code":"hsdfh", "flag":"dfsg43", "filterVal": 50},
        ];
```

is expected to be conferted into

```
var new_arr[0] = [{"code":"kfk", "flag":"dfmk", "filterVal": 0}];//0s
var new_arr[1]= [{"code":"asdf", "flag":"34t", "filterVal": 10},];//10s
var new_arr[2]= [{"code":"asg", "flag":"sdg3", "filterVal": 50},{"code":"hsdfh", "flag":"dfsg43", "filterVal": 50}];//50s
var new_arr[3]= [];//60s
```

Comment: please add the original array and the wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz Just added.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use plain Javascript and an array for the grouping.

```js
var array = [{ "code": "kfk", "flag": "dfmk", "filterVal": 0 }, { "code": "asg", "flag": "sdg3", "filterVal": 50 }, { "code": "asdf", "flag": "34t", "filterVal": 10 }, { "code": "hsdfh", "flag": "dfsg43", "filterVal": 50 }, ],
    groups = [{ filterVal: 0 }, { filterVal: 10 }, { filterVal: 50 }, { filterVal: 60 }],
    result = groups.map(function (a) { return []; });

array.forEach(function (a) {
    groups.some(function (b, i) {
        var k = Object.keys(b)[0];
        return a[k] === b[k] && result[i].push(a);
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Or you could use a more linear approach

```js
var array = [{ "code": "kfk", "flag": "dfmk", "filterVal": 0 }, { "code": "asg", "flag": "sdg3", "filterVal": 50 }, { "code": "asdf", "flag": "34t", "filterVal": 10 }, { "code": "hsdfh", "flag": "dfsg43", "filterVal": 50 }, ],
    filter = [{ filterVal: 0 }, { filterVal: 10 }, { filterVal: 50 }, { filterVal: 60 }],
    groups = Object.create(null),
    result = filter.map(function (a) { return []; });

filter.forEach(function (b, i) {
    groups[b[Object.keys(b)[0]]] = i;
});
array.forEach(function (a) {
    result[groups[a.filterVal]].push(a);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry for reasking. Looks like your code works (thanks a lot). My code works. The question was if it is possible to make it more compact - one line instead of four...   Anyway I'm upvoting for your answer. Again, thank you.

Comment: to answer the question, no, not really.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom filter:

```
app.filter('groupify', function(){
  return function(list, key) {
    return list.reduce((carry, row) => {
      if (!carry[row[key]]) carry[row[key]] = [];
      carry[row[key]].push(row);
      return carry;
    }, {});
  };
});
```

And use it:

```
 var new_arr = $filter('groupify')(arr, 'filterVal');
```

You'll get an object: `{0: [...], 10: [...], 50: [...], 60: [...]}`
It's easy to transform it to array if it neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
var new_arr = [0, 10, 50, 60].map(function (n) { 
    return $filter('filter')(arr, { filterVal: n }, true); 
});
```